# Pull Excel Data Table entries into recipients for Outlook email template

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The goal is to connect an Excel data table/pivot table to an Outlook email template.

Is there a way to pull the original entry creator out of a pivot table or table field into the recipient section to send an email? I'm trying to automate emailing multiple users from this data table. The information on who to email is in the table.

This what I have so far:

```
Sub SendMail()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application 
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem 
    Dim  blRunning As Boolean

    blRunning = True 
    on Error Resume Next 
    Set olApp = GetObject (,"Outlook.Application") 
    If olApp Is Nothing Then 
        Set olApp = New Outlook.Application 
        blRunning = False 
    End If  
    On Error GoTo 0 

    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
    With olMail 
        .Subject = "Automatic Entry Support" 
        .Recipients.Add "J.Doe@gmail.com"  
        .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\J.Doe\Documents\Project\Template draft.xlsx"  
        .Body = "Support message" 
        .Display ("Spell check, data attached?, SEND")
    End With
    If Not blRunning Then olApp.Quit

    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the last row of your table and for loop through recipients. Check this out:

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm